# Selenium with Python: collecting an email from a form with read only

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to collect email addresses from a form on a website that has readonly inside of it.

```
<input name="email" id="email" type="text" class="form-control" value="example@gmail.com" readonly="">
```

I want to be able to get the email address (example@gmail.com) but everything I try returns "unable to locate element".

Everything is configured properly as the rest of the script is working fine, which I have left out.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
import os

x = 0

all_volunteers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@title="View volunteer record"]')
for volunteer in all_volunteers:
    volunteer.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    # email_add = driver.find_element_by_id('emaillabel')
    #email_add = driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_name('email'))
    #print(email_add.get_attribute('email'))
    #email_add = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input id')
    #email_add = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input [@name="email"]')
    #email_add = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('Email Address')
    email_add = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
    print(email_add.get_attribute('value'))
    # back button
    driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
    #increase counter by 1
    x += 1
```

Everything commented out (followed by #) is what I have tried.

Is any one able to tell me what I am doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Not that this is a solution but rather just a quick symptom check - what if you put `time.sleep(10)` after the `volunteer.click()` line - same thing?

Comment: Thanks for the reply alecxe. Unfortunately adding time.sleep(10) did not work. The program was still unable to locate element.

Comment: ok, thanks for checking! Are there any iframes on the page?

Answer (score 0):

I have a debugging solution to locate the element.

- In the browser, open the web page containing the email input
- Open developer tools (F12)
- Open console tab in the developer tools
- Type `$x('//input[@id="email"]')` and see if the element is located. This is the native xpath locator
- You can also try `document.getElementById('email')` in the console

If the element is not found still, try the iFrame selector marked in the screenshot to identify iframes and switch to it.

[image]
If more than one element is returned, it means that you might have to modify the selector to find unique element.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Sighil.

Both of the commands work in the console, however I think you are right and the email is in an iframe. I am using firefox for this project. When using the iframe selector in the firefox developer tools the iframe that I think the information is in is in position 4. However when I look through the html it is the second iframe to appear. It does not appear to be embedded in the first iframe but follows immediately after.

Comment: <iframe id="oauth2relay273829554" 
    name"oauth2relay273829554" 
  
  src'https://accounts.google.coom/o/oauth2/postmessageRelay? 
  
 parent...ykSDofgA%2Fm%3D_features3rpctoken=763363034&forcesecure=1" style="width":1px; heigh: 1px; 
    position: absolute; top: -100px;" tabindex="-1" areia- 
   hidden="true">...</iframe>